# How to display animation before page loads?

Tags: javascript, jquery, oracle-apex

I am trying to display wait animation from https://lottiefiles.com/

I created a JavaScript function, a region on the page 0 and call the function with dynamic action and it works, but display animation with all regions together.

Function:

```
function createLoadAnimation() {
   document.getElementById("LoadAnimation1").innerHTML = "";
   const anim2 = lottie.loadAnimation({
       container: document.getElementById('LoadAnimation1'),
       path: `https://assets10.lottiefiles.com/packages/lf20_wd6xyqkx.json`,
       renderer: 'svg',
       loop: false,
       autoplay: true,
       });
};
```

How to display animation when users waiting for page load?

Comment: Can please you provide an executable example with SO code snippets?https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356678/stack-overflow-run-code-snippet

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the loader to the page and display it initially. Then once the page load is complete, you need to hide the loader as soon as possible.

HTML:

```
  </head>
  <body onload="removeLoader();">
    <!-- Loader here -->
    <div id="loader"><p id="loader-content">Loading...</p></div>
    
    <div>Inner content here</div>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
html {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

#loader {
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  z-index: 99999;  
  background: #f30
}

#loader p {  
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 100px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

JS:

```
function removeLoader(){
     let loader = document.getElementById('loader');
  
  // hide the loader
  loader.style = 'display: none;';
  }
```

[**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/ExpertKiD/pen/wvderbG)

Answer (score 0):

The **Ariel's** answer will not work for you as you would like to.

The problem is, that this solution first draw html which is connected to external css and js. It takes a while to load js and especially with library like lottie is.

The best way to prevent this problem is load just lottie and css you need to make loadpage first. Don't be afraid to use some basic css inline!! I know, it is not recommended, but note, it will render in the same time with your html, so there is no chance to blink default content before load animation comes in.

It is enough to write inline style for absolute position of the container.

See this page:
https://www.hviezdne-byvanie.sk/

The green container has inline styles. Everything else, loads after it. You have no chance to see content before you see loading animation.